# Laravel tests request set body

Tags: laravel, testing, request, phpunit

I have an API that uses `$request->getContent();` to get the body (which is JSON) and I want to write some feature tests to test this endpoint but I can't find a way to set the body in a Laravel feature test:

```
public function testSuccessfullyProcessed()
{
    $json = '<json>';

    $response = $this->get('/api/process');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

there isn't something like `$this->setBody` or `$this->setContent` according to `Visual Studio Code`. I've searched through the methods of `$this` and can't find a method to do this?

I've spent some time googling various things but I only find info on how to get the body.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to set the body of your request; if so, you can pass the data in the second parameter of a post request in the following way.

```
public function testSuccessfullyProcessed()
{
    $testData = [
        'my_data_1' => 'Test Data'
    ];

    $response = $this->post('/api/process', $testData);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

If you intend to set the request's response manually, I think you might have gotten something mixed up as this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Problem is my data isn't an associative array instead it is simple JSON encoded string.

Comment: @PetarVasilev Then [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first

Comment: But I need to accept it that way at the endpoint. @BrianThompson

Comment: @PetarVasilev It sounds like you need to update your question with all of the relevant details. If you *need* the JSON to remain an encoded string in the controller, then you could just assign it to a property in the request `$this->post('..', ['data' => $json])`, but this seems like an odd requirement. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70081885/edit) your question to include exactly what your desired outcome is.

Comment: @BrianThompson I want at the endpoint `$request->getContent()` to return the JSON and then proceed to decode it and use it.

Comment: @PetarVasilev why you want to do so, if you can directly do `$request->json('key')` or `$request->input('key')` and you should have the json already decoded for you... read the documentation...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I want to because it has already been done so and it needs to stay the same way.